# Filtering through Hough transform results in DLIB

Tags: c++, hough-transform, dlib

I am trying to use Hough transform from DLIB but can't get more than one line to show. The example in DLIB docs use just one, strong point:

```
point p = max_point(mat(himg));
```

How can I get all strong (above certain threshold or N most votes) lines to show?

I've tried to loop through the points and mask each already found, but the `dlib::max_point` keeps finding the same, point despite it being zeroed out already:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nPoints; ++i){
    dlib::point p = dlib::max_point(dlib::mat(hImg));
    maxPoints.push_back(p);
    std::cout << "Turning point " << p.x() << ", " << p.y() << " = " << hImg[p.x()][p.y()] << std::endl;

    hImg[p.x()][p.y()] = 0;

    std::pair<dlib::point, dlib::point> line = ht.get_line(p);

    dlib::draw_line(temp, line.first+5, line.second+5, dlib::rgb_pixel(255,255,0));
}
```

which produces the same value after the first loop iteration:

```
Turning point 595, 584 = 78540
Turning point 595, 584 = 0
Turning point 595, 584 = 0
```

Is there a "correct" approach to filtering through hough space in DLIB?

UPDATE:
As Davis King pointed, I swapped the coordinates (row, col) vs (x, y) which solved the immediate problem, but the core issue is still there.
My hough space looks like this:

[image: Hough Image in color for clarity]

As can be seen, there's a number of local maxima, but everything gets dominated by the huge blob in the middle. My initial idea was that every blurry area can be reduced to a single most dominant point

I was thinking about clustering every blob of points above certain threshold, but looping through the entire image to find such points AND feeding points found to the clustering algorithm will be very inefficient so there must be a smarter way, perhaps the inner edges of the image itself could be suppressed (small objects like irregular clutter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the row and column swapped.  `hImg[p.x()][p.y()] = 0;` is backwards, it should be  `hImg[p.y()][p.x()] = 0;`

Comment: Thanks, I sometimes mix up when having one place use x,y and the other row,col